# Проблема с цепочкой методов в php

Tags: ооп, php

Есть код и такая вот ошибка Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in Z:\home\localhost\www\blog\setting.php on line 29. В чем проблема и пути её решения?

```
<?
define('SERVER','localhost');
define('LOGIN','admin');
define('PASSWD','12345');
define('DB','blog');

class DataBase {

function connect () {
$connect = mysql_connect(SERVER,LOGIN,PASSWD);
if (!$connect) die ('Проблема с соединением '. mysql_error());
        $usedb = mysql_select_db(DB, $connect);
        if (!$usedb) die ('Проблема с базой'. mysql_error());

    return $this;
}

    function createtb() {
    $query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articls` (`id` INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                              `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                              `date` DATETIME,
                                              `text` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)';
    mysql_query($query) or die ('Ошибка'. mysql_error());
    return $this;
    }

    function close () { 
    $close = mysql_close($connect); 
    }

}
$db = new DataBase;
$db->connect()->createtb()->close();
```

Comment: А `$connect` он откуда возьмет? Сделайте переменную `$connect` приватным свойством класса и при закрытии проверяйте что она не `null`

    class DataBase {
        private $connect = null;

        function connect() {
            $this -> connect = mysql_connect(SERVER, LOGIN, PASSWD);
            ...
            return $this;
        }
        ...
        function close() {
            if ($this -> connect) {
                mysql_close($this -> connect);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Вы в методе close() используете переменную, которую объявили в методе connect(). Ее область видимости ограничена методом connect(). Объявите ее как свойство метода, и обращайтесь через $this->connect

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё получилось.